Seeking a Brisker-style shiurim book on Masechet Beitza (besides Birkat Avraham)
I'm looking for a Brisker-style book of shiurim on Masechet Beitza. I'm already familiar with the Birkat Avraham, so I'm interested in recommendations for other works that provide in-depth analysis in the Brisker tradition.
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Not a full book on Beitzah alone, but R. Aryeh Pomeranchik's Emek Berachah contains plenty of chiddushim on Beitzah, in particular on pages 113-119.
R. Pomeranchik was a close student of the Brisker Rav, so hopefully this gives you something of what you are looking for.

Hi @Joel K Thank you! can't find it on Hebrew books, any leads?

I don't think it's on Hebrew Books. You can access it via Otzar HaChochmah. I believe you'll be able to access the relevant pages if you sign up for free to the site. https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/155405/p/111/t/10.40.26796973219664544/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1727675486820

Found it thank you!

There is Kovetz Shiurim from R' Elchonon Wasserman.

Thank you I have it!

This surely fits the bill: Rav Kulefsky's chiddushim on Beitzah
